# Commands after unittest don't execute

Tags: python, unit-testing, execution

I imported unittest in python 3.6, and used it like so:

```
class TestFunc(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_half(self):
            pass
        def test_merge(self):
            pass
        def test_decrypt(self):
            pass
        def test_rank(self):
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("printing before calling unittest")
    unittest.main()
    print("printing after calling unittest")
```

the output looks like this:

```
 printing before calling unittest
    ....
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.001s

OK

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and the second call to `print` i.e. `print("printing after calling unittest")`, does not execute. 
Why is it that I can't do anything after unittest? How can I continue with the code after testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) explain this:

> By default `main` calls `sys.exit()` with an exit code indicating success or failure of the tests run.

`sys.exit()` exits the script immediately, so your final line is never called.

You can avoid this behaviour by passing `exit=False`:

```
unittest.main(exit=False)
```

Comment: I was slow again :p. Yup

Comment: After adding `exit=False`, now when test cases are failed even then rest of the code lines are executing. Is there a quick way to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition to previous answer. Yes, `exit=False` is working perfectly but I faced the situation when test case was failed and even then rest of the program was running (it was expected as per current logic). Ideally, program should stop in case of any test case failure. In that case, I simply did this.

```
status = unittest.main(exit=False)
if len(status.result.failures) == 0 and len(status.result.errors) == 0:
    # normal remaining execution
else:
    # exit
```